# Xcode GUI adjusting location of Navigator-Menu

Tags: xcode, settings, ui

How can one adjust the view settings, so that the Navigator-Menu (see image) appears on the right or on the bottom, *etc.*?

[image: Xcode]

**UPDATE:** Thanks, *jherran*, for telling me the name of this menu.

Answer (score 1):

It's called the Navigation Area and you can't change it's position, but you can hide the menu with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>.

To unhide it, just type <kbd>⌘</kbd> plus a number from <kbd>1</kbd> to <kbd>8</kbd> depending the tab you want to show.

Comment: Hello, thanks. I know, one can hide this. I merely want to know, how to position it, when I have it unhidden. Would you happen to know, what this menu is called? Cheers.

Comment: Update my answer, it's called the Navigation Area.

Comment: Thanks! (Sorry, I apparently need to acquire more reputation-points, in order to give you a +1.)